# MS Visual Studio 2022 doesn't connect in Firebird 4

Tags: firebird, visual-studio-2022, firebird-.net-provider, firebird-4.0

I migrated my Firebird 2.5 database to Firebird 4.0 and now I can not connect the MS Visual Studio 2022, I've tried several things but nothing works, someone has an idea how to solve this?

I just keep getting the message: connection rejected by remote interface

Comment: Which version of the Firebird .net provider are you using? You need to use a fairly recent one to connect with the default Firebird 4.0 settings, or you need to add the Legacy_Auth to the AuthServer setting, and change the WireCrypt to Enabled (instead of default of Required).

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["connection rejected by remote interface" in C# program connecting to Firebird 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47786337/connection-rejected-by-remote-interface-in-c-sharp-program-connecting-to-fireb)

Comment: Also [Trying to connect to Firebird 4.0 from remote always generate error "connection rejected by remote interface"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70168293/trying-to-connect-to-firebird-4-0-from-remote-always-generate-error-connection)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks for the guidance. I used this one https://firebirdsql.org/en/net-provider/ , but it doesn´t work. Can you tell me if you have a newer one?

Comment: Exactly which version are you using, and what is the value of `AuthServer` and `WireCrypt` in the firebird.conf of your Firebird 4.0 server?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, good morning, I used AuthServer=Srp256,Srp,Legacy_auth, AuthClient=Srp256,Srp,Legacy_auth, UserManager=Srp,Legacy_UserManager and WireCrypt=Enabled, but no connect. I'm using the user = SYSDBA and pass = masterkey, Do I need to create a new user?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel i´m using firebird 4.0

Comment: I meant the version of the FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient library. In any case, you probably are now trying to connect with a Legacy_Auth SYSDBA, and you need to create one explicitly for Srp (users exist per authentication plugin).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel my operacional system is windows 10 64 bits

Comment: @MarkRotteveel you can send me a FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient library please, The library you are using

Comment: Use the latest from NuGet, and make sure your user was created for the Srp authentication plugin.

Comment: In any case, maybe it is better if you ask your question on https://groups.google.com/g/firebird-net-provider